# Program on top of tor

Tags: c, network-programming, tor

Is there a way to write a program on top of tor?

I would like to write a ncurses mail program that uses tor for connections; the base of my program will be done with GPGME api's - for encrypting and decrypting e-mail -,  therefore I would to connect my mail client on tor network for sending e-mail.

The concept is simple:

```
alice : Mail -> encrypting (bob pulic key) > Tor network -> Bob
bob: decrypting mail -> new mail -> encrypting (alice pub key)  -> Tor network -> Alice
```

In these days I'm learning GPGME but my problem is Tor, is there a way to do that? API's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tor would be pretty useless if every program that used it had to be aware of it.  Tor is simply acting as a proxy server.  Give your mail client the ability to work with a proxy server (`SOCKS`) and it will automatically be able to use tor.

Comment: I agree with you. but i was hoping that I could connect in some way my mail client to the tor "hidden service". many thanks!

Comment: Perhaps for convenience you would *also* want this application to give the user a hand managing their Tor client. But that's a completely separate issue from how the application actually connects. In principle some users might not want the app to use SOCKS for Tor at all, they could in theory have Tor implemented on their router. Or they might have their own Tor-like client that offers a SOCKS interface, that they want to use instead of whatever Tor capability you would have built in to the mail program.

Comment: Assuming you have tor listening on port 9050 somewhere, your mail client is configured to use a proxy at `<someip>:9050` where `<someip>` is probably `localhost`.  Your mailclient needs to be proxy aware or you you need to use some kind of shim layer like [freecap](http://www.freecap.ru/eng/?p=whatis).  If you are writing the mail client and want to enforce the use of Tor, simply hard code the proxy connection IP addresses etc within your app so the user cannot turn them off.  But as @Steve Jessop points out thats not the _only_ way of connecting to Tor.

Comment: If you want to be a hidden-service, you just listen as a normal server on a local port and configure Tor to advertise a port for that hidden service at a .onion address. So, nothing magic; this is how a Web server shows up on .onion addresses (just as easily a git server could as well). The only restriction is that only TCP works.

Answer (score 3):

You can look into the tor control protocol. There are two Python libraries to communicate to Tor via this protocol (one synchronous called Stem and one asynchronous on top of Twisted called txtorcon). Using these, you may reconfigure the underlying Tor to set up a hidden service pointed at a local endpoint.